# Python setattr: Affect Object's iterable property - but only at a specific location

Tags: python, numpy

Say I have an object `myObj`, which contains an `np.array()` `prop`. I can change any index like

```
myObj.prop[10] = 20
```

Now, I am iterating over several variables (properties) of that object, and changing them all. I can do this like

```
vars = {'me', 'you', 'everyone'}
for var in vars:
    setattr(myObj, var, newValues[var])
```

The part I'm confused in is if I want to only change an array in one particular place. Let the index be `idx`. How could I affect in this manner `Obj.prop[idx]`? `setattr(myObj, prop[idx], newValue)` obviously won't work. Do I need to copy the whole `prop` array, change its value at `idx`, and use setattr on that?

Answer (score 1):

For something like - `Obj.prop[idx] = newValue` - you can use [`getattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) built-in function instead of the [`setattr()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr) built-in function . Example -

```
getattr(myObj, prop)[idx] = newValue
```

Demo -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.x = [1,2,3]
...
>>> c = CA()
>>> getattr(c,'x')
[1, 2, 3]
>>> getattr(c,'x')[1] = 10
>>> getattr(c,'x')
[1, 10, 3]
```